# Awaiting a dynamic import

Tags: reactjs, typescript, async-await

I've created a web application with React and Typescript, using [create-react-app](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript). It uses a rather heavy third party library. I want to exclude that from the main bundle by using [dynamic import expressions](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/project/dynamic-import-expressions.html).

So, instead of doing `import { Component } from 'library'`, I've created a little wrapper that looks like this:

```
const loadLibrary = async () => {
    const x = await import('library').then((r) => r);
    return x;
};
const {
    Component,
} = loadLibrary() as any;

// tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
console.log(`typeof Component is ${typeof Component}`);

export {
    Component,
};
```

And then, in my app, I'd use `import { Component } from '../library-wrapper.ts'`.
Because the wrapper uses dynamic import expressions, Webpack creates a separate chunk which is only downloaded by the browser then it is actually needed. `\o/`.

But the bad news is: my wrapper doesn't actually await the dynamic import expression. It invokes the `loadLibrary()` function but immediately continues execution, logging

> typeof Component is undefined

So when I attempt to use the `Component`, React crashes:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

Any suggestions what is going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`loadLibrary` is an asynchronous function, so it returns a promise instead of a regular object. Therefore you have to do `await loadLibrary()` or `loadLibrary().then(...)` to get the library object.

A consequence of this is that you can't statically export something that's imported dynamically, because static imports/export are done immediately and synchronously while dynamic imports are done asynchronously. You can only export the function `loadLibrary`, and let users of the module call that when they need the library.

In short, once asynchronous, always asynchronous; you can't force something asynchronous to run synchronously in JavaScript.

---

Also, as an aside, your `loadLibrary` function could be simplied a lot, to just

```
const loadLibrary = () => import('library');
```

since a) `.then((r) => r)` just creates an identical copy of a promise, b)  you don't have to await before returning in an async function (it's done automatically) and c) a function that returns a promise anyways doesn't have to be marked as `async` (although you still can if you wish, for readability for example).

Comment: I thought the whole idea of [async/await](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/async-await.html) is that you could actually _wait_ for a `Promise` to be resolved. Have I been wrong in this case?

Comment: Yes, you're right, but you still have to use the `await` keyword to wait for a promise (to tell JS that it's the result of a promise you want instead of the promise itself). And because you can't run asynchronous code in a synchronous way (which I believe is due to the single-treaded design of JavaScript), you can only use `await` inside a function marked as `async`, otherwise you would have to use `.then(r => { /* do something with result */ })`.

Answer (score 1):

I made an IIFE that receives a prop named pdfName:

```js
const Component = ({ pdfName }) => {
const [pdf, setPdf] = useState(undefined);

(async () => {
    if (pdfName !== '') {
      await import(`../../assets/docs/${pdfName}.pdf`).then((r) => {
        setPdf(r.default);
      });
    }
  })();
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, application crashed with undefined "Popup", "Confirm" constants.
Loading it using React Lazy - solved this problem !

```
const Popup = lazy(() => import("./Popup"));
const Confirm = lazy(() => import("./Confirm"));
```

[image]